Pauli exclusion principle and electrons of two atoms in gas
Based on the Pauli prohibition principle, two electrons cannot be in the same quantum state ( any of the 4 quantum numbers for an atom do not coincide) in an atom. Why Pauli's prohibition principle does not apply to a quantum system of two or three atoms (e.g. hydrogen gas)? Is it because the wave function of an electron (fermion) in one atom is in a different place compared to another atom?

Yes; but if you think just about that, you will inevitably run into a dead end. Instead, you should be considering the molecular orbital as the fundamentally possible quantum states to look at, and then you can see that Pauli's Exclusion Principle holds strictly true for them.

Thanks for answer
